# iOS camera permissions :Camera appears black on iphone and ipad(UIImagePickerController issue iOS 9 )

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

In my app,I have used the following code to access the camera to change the profile pic of the user.But I can't access the camera.

```
 if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
 if(isIOS8SystemVersion)
        {
            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
            }];
        }
        else
        {
            [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
        }
```

This code works fine on iPhone 4(16gb) with iOS 7.x .***But in iOS 9,the presented viewController appears as a black screen and I can't take the picture.The same is the case with the photoLibrary***.The same code works well for my other app in the same device.

I went through many questions in Stack Overflow and tried many solutions.But they did not work for me.Like making a singleton for UIImagePIcker controller etc..etc.

In **settings->privacy->camera->**  I can't see my app listed in this section.

What all are the things to be done in order that an iOS app can access Camera and photos?Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Just delay your function to open camera and it will work fine :D
Use below code:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(showCamera) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];


-(void)showCamera
{
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    if(isIOS8SystemVersion)
    {
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first call this method and determine permission of camera

```
-(void)PermissionForCamera
{
    NSString *mediaType = AVMediaTypeVideo;
    AVAuthorizationStatus authStatus = [AVCaptureDevice authorizationStatusForMediaType:mediaType];

    if(authStatus == AVAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
    {
        NSLog(@"AVAuthorizationStatusAuthorized");
        // run your code for camera
        ImagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        [ImagePicker setDelegate:self];
        ImagePicker = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            [self ImagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
        }];
    }
    else if(authStatus == AVAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
    {
        NSLog(@"AVAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined");
        // run your code for camera
        ImagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        [ImagePicker setDelegate:self];
        ImagePicker = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            [self ImagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        // turn on the camera permission from settings
    }


}
```

Comment: This is just a usual permission check right?My problem is that the access is not granted to use the camera, and In settings->privacy->camera-> I can't see my app listed in this section.

Comment: In case you are or someone else is still looking, the settings are not under privacy, it is under settings->[your app]->Camera.